# How to prevent reposting of data before refresh?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose there is button on which there is event for adding the total sum(there is coloumn Amount in gridview) and posting the data in gridview i.e update of gridview. I want that when user  click on button it will update the gridview i.e data will inserted in geridview but it will not add current numeric value  to the total sum unless user refresh the page.

For this how to do?  Please tell me.

Comment: take a look at the ASP.NET UpdatePanel control.

Answer (score -1):

You can use telerik's ASP.NET AJAX controls.
Visit here http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx